# How to get notification when someone likes or comments via Facebook Social Plugin

Tags: php, facebook, joomla, social-networking

I have integrated the Facebook Social Plugin into my Joomla Website.
I have a Like button and a Comment box.

How can I get notified when someones Likes the page?
How do I view a list of users who Liked the page?
How do I get notified when someone comments on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using XFBML or an iframe to implement the Like button? I If you're using XFBML, you can give Facebook a callback function whenever an event happens through Facebook. When someone 'likes' your webpage, Facebook generates an event called 'edge.create', as listed [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).

You can get some information from your users via http://www.facebook.com/insights.

Similarly, when someone comments on your page, a 'comments.add' event is fired.

There's more information about the Facebook 'like' button in Facebook's own [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).

**Edit:**

Judging from this passage found in Facebook's documentation :

*The XFBML version is more versatile, but requires use of the JavaScript SDK. The XFBML dynamically re-sizes its height according to whether there are profile pictures to display, gives you the ability (through the Javascript library) to **listen for like events** so that you know in real time when a user clicks the Like button, and it always gives the user the ability to add an optional comment to the like.*

It doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: Is this possible with the iframe version?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the iFrame version. You need to the JS version.