# Reward users for liking a facebook page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Ive seen sites do it, where they say "like us on facebook to recieve 5 free points" or something like that. I run an incentive site where users earn points then spend them on things. Any idea how to implement this concept: a user likes our facebook page and the site automatically rewards them points?

Comment: You must implement a notification callback - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678309/how-to-get-notification-when-someone-likes-or-comments-via-facebook-social-plugi

Comment: But how do you know if the user really likes it, or has just clicked the button to get paid?

Comment: Navigate the user to the Facebook page, and run a FQL query on returning to the page of the sort of : "SELECT 1 FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me() and page_id = xxxxxxxxx" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255435/checking-which-users-have-liked-a-facebook-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog article](http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2011/12/05/social-currency-giving-back-to-your-customers-for-promoting-your-app/) by LessEverything has a nice explanation on how to do exactly this.